# React cannot read property 'map' of undefined on component

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I have a data from third party API like:

```
{
  "title": "some title",
  "genres": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "name": :Family",
    },{
      // another object goes below for movie genre
    }
  ]
}
```

I send the data from parent to child as structure above,
I try to recurring the data from `genres`.

The parent:

`<Datacard movieSingle={this.state.movieSingle} />`

The children:

```
let movieData = this.props.movieSingle;
const genreItems = movieData.genres.map((genre) => 
  <span>{genre.name}</span>
);
```

I got error like `TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined`

I try to `console.log(this.props.movieSingle)` on the child and I got like:

```
>[]
>[]
>{adult: false, backdrop_path: "/1EGFjibWzsN2GNNeOSQBYhQ9pK5.jpg", belongs_to_collection: null, budget: 0, genres: Array(3), …}
>{adult: false, backdrop_path: "/1EGFjibWzsN2GNNeOSQBYhQ9pK5.jpg", belongs_to_collection: null, budget: 0, genres: Array(3), …}
```

From what I read `map()` is available on array and the genres is array, or did I miss something?
Thank you :)

Comment: Please show a full reproducible example. See [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: can you provide with `console.log(this.props.movieSingle)`?

Comment: I just update the question, or I need to add something?

Comment: Would you share your parent component code?

Comment: @BeHappy should I update the question or use third party?

Comment: No, Just update question and add parent component code. I am wondering why two times you get empty array instead on object.

Comment: @BeHappy https://pastebin.com/UunxbYk8 -> parent, https://pastebin.com/59jRBJEu -> children. I fear that the question will be too long, so I posted on pastebin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Error is occurred because the code is also run when the data is not fetched yet from API.
So please add condition in render function like this.

```
let movieData = this.props.movieSingle;
const genreItems = movieData.genres ? movieData.genres.map((genre) => 
  <span>{genre.name}</span>
) : [];
```

Comment: I have a few question:
1. Why i have 4 log on single ```console.log()```?
2. Another data like title, tagline etc is being rendered normally. Why is that?
3. Using your code answer will it wait for the data and re-rendered the component?
Thank you for answering...

Comment: 1. render function is called whenever props and states are updated. 4 log means the component was updated 4 times.
2. title and tagline were manipulated when the render function was called in first time.
3. That doesn't mean waiting. Until data is fetched, it displays nothing. Once data is fetched, render function is called again and displays list of spans.

Answer (score 0):

When you fetch data, it is updated asynchronously, so you should `.map` when its available:

```
// Optional chaining syntax
const genreItems = movieData?.genres.map((genre) => <span>{genre.name}</span>) ?? [];

// Or
const genreItems = movieData.genres
  ? movieData.genres.map((genre) => <span>{genre.name}</span>)
  : [];
```

Comment: Thank you for answering, I just update my code using code like yours above...

Answer (score 0):

Notice the first two instances of your `console.log(this.props.movieSingles)` its `>[]` right, for those first two children whose `this.props.movieSingles` is equals to `[]`, `this.props.movieSingles.genres` is equal to `undefined`, hence cannot use `map()` for the first two instances.

Comment: Thank you for answer, I just realize I need to wait for the data. The error is coming because the data is not available and I try to ```map()``` it isn't?